# How to populate a relation with an axiom in event b

Tags: event-b

So, I have a Rodin event-b project and would like to define a known static relation. For examples sake, lets say I have a set {a,b,c} and would like to specify the relation constant which is equal to {(a,1),(a,2),(b,3)} in an context axiom. (May be multilined, but preferably single if feasable)

How would I go about this?

```
CONTEXT

example 

SETS

list 

CONSTANTS  
a       
b  
c 

relation 

AXIOMS

axm1   :    partition(list, {a}, {b}, {c}) 

axm2   :    relation ∈ list↔1‥5 

axm3   : ???


END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
axm3:  relation = {a↦1, a↦2, b↦3}
```